# How do I combine the default function with other text processing functions

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

This does not work:

```
{{ print "my.prefix/" (.Values.Derp) ".suffix:"}}{{ mustToJson .Values.my.value | default "sdfsdfsdf"}}
```

If `.Values.my.value` is not set the rendered yaml is:

```
my.prefix/DERP_VALUE.suffix:null
```

If I remove the mustToJson function this works:

```
{{ print "my.prefix/" (.Values.Derp) ".suffix:"}}{{ .Values.my.value | default "sdfsdfsdf"}}
```

If .Values.my.value is null the rendered yaml is:

```
my.prefix/DERP_VALUE.suffix:sdfsdfsdf
```

How can I pass `.Values.my.value` through `mustToJson` and also set a default value?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like in your example `.Values.my.value` is Go `nil`, which `mustToJson` serializes to JSON `null`; since that's not an empty string then `default` won't take effect.

If you're okay with your default value also getting JSON serialized then you can just change the order of the function invocations:

```
{{ .Values.my.value | default "sdfsdfsdf" | mustToJson }}
```

This will produce the string `"sdfsdfsdf"` as a JSON string out.

Another alternative is to spell out the conditional:

```
{{- with .Values.my.value -}}
{{- mustToJson . -}}
{{- else -}}
sdfsdfsdf
{{- end -}}
```

If `Values.my.value` is `null` (or an empty string, 0, or an empty map or list) then you'll get the literal string `sdfsdfsdf` with no additional quotes.